# Using javascript to get a value from html input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am new to this forum and I want to be able to get a value from my html inputs into javascript. Right now i have this code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PWS</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#009933" text="#FFFFFF">
<H1 align="center">PWS Julia en Sophie</H1>
<hr>
<br>

<strong>DOUCHE</strong>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Temperatuur</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dtemp" onClick="calculateTotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Tijd</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dtijd" onClick="calculateTotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Hoe vaak per week</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dfreq" onClick="calculateTotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>
<strong>BAD</strong>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Temperatuur</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="btemp" onClick="calculateTotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Hoe vaak per week</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bfreq" onClick="calculateTotal()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dTemp = document.getElementsByName("dtemp").value;
    document.write(dTemp);
</script>
```

obviously, its not working. Because the dTemp value stays undefined.
Can anyone help me, thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: It returns a collection. So access it like `var dTemp = document.getElementsByName("dtemp")[0].value;`

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array, so you have to reference the position of the element:

```
var dTemp = document.getElementsByName("dtemp")[0].value;
```

I would also recommend giving ID's to your inputs, since it seems that each name is unique in your case, that way you could use `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName("dtemp")` will give you array of elements, traverse through one by one and get the value from it.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("dtemp");
var firstValue = elements[0].value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys,
i adjusted the code so that it takes the first item from the arrays:

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var dTemp = document.getElementsByName("dtemp")[0].value;
  document.write(dTemp);
    </script>

However, nothing is showing up where I would normally expect the output to be, so it doesnt print the dTemp value.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to index the result of `getElementsByName`, as described in other answers; append `[0]` to `document.getElementsByName("dtemp")`.

2) You can’t use `document.write` in code that is executed after the page has loaded. It would replace the current document by the written content. Write to an element instead.

3) You have not defined the function `calculateTotal` at all. Wrap your JavaScript code in a function, e.g.

```
<div id=result></div>
<script>
function calculateTotal() {
    var dTemp = document.getElementsByName("dtemp")[0].value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dTemp; }
</script>
```

4) You have a long way to go, since now your code makes no attempt at calculating anything, you should hardly use `onclick` on an `input` element to start the calculation (rather, `onchange` on it, or `onclick` on a separate button element). You should read a good JavaScript primer, really.